# Counting number of words in a File, then writing the results to another File

Tags: java, file-io, printwriter

I need to read in a file named "input.txt" and then count the words that are in that file. I then have to write them to another file named output.txt.

Ex: input.txt has the following words "The quick QUICK brown fox"

output.txt should look like this:

1 The

2 quick

3 brown

4 fox

So far I have the following code, but do not know if I am even on the right path.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountWords {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    File file = new File("input.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
    int count = 0;
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String word = sc.next();
        if (word.indexOf("\\") == -1){
            count++;
            writer.printf("%3d",count + " " + word);  //should print ----> |   # word|

        }
        break;
    }
    writer.close(); //close print writer
    sc.close();    //close input file
}

}
```

Comment: Your output example doesn't correspond to your description. You said you wanted a count of the words in the file. But there **fox** appears only once, not 4 times, **brown** appears once, not 3 times, etc.

Comment: If you really do want to count words and it's just your example that's wrong, then you can't output anything until you've read all of the input (what if the first word and the last word in the input are the same for example). You'll need to keep track of unique words and count the occurrences, so look at the Map interface and its various implementors.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a word is characters separated by a space, you can easily use the stream API as follow to count number of words in a file :

```
 final long count = Files.lines( Paths.get( "myFile.txt") )
                         .flatMap( line -> Stream.of( line.split( "[ ]+" ) ) )
                         .collect( Collectors.counting( ) );
```

And if you need repartition by word :

```
final Map<String, Long> collect =
    Files.lines( Paths.get( "myFile.txt" ) )
         .flatMap( line -> Stream.of( line.split( "[ ]+" ) ) )
         .map( String::toLowerCase ) // to count quick and QUICK as same
         .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( Function.identity( ), Collectors.counting( ) ) );
```

where the key of the map is the word and value is the number of this word in file

Comment: Use `.flatMap(Pattern.compile("\\s+")::splitAsStream)`. This way you will not recompile the regexp for every line and will not create intermediate arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your file is a text file since you said `input.txt`. Now, to the actual code:

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(file); //Where file is your file
HashMap<String, Integer> words = new HashMap<>(); //Where you will be saving your words
while(scn.hasNext()){
    String str = scn.next().toLowerCase();
    words.put(str, words.containsKey(str)?words.get(str)+1:1);
}
```

Now you have the `words` map with all words and their # of appereances.
To write them to another file:

```
String build = "";
for(String str : words.keySet()){
    if(build!="")build+="\n";
    build+=words.get(str)+" "+str;
}
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputfile.getAbsoluteFile()));
bw.write(build);
bw.close();
```

**Example:**
Lets assume you have an input.txt with the following content:

```
The quick brown fox JUMPED over jumped the lazy brown DOG QUICK dog
```

Now, the scanner will go through each word, as the default delimeter is ' ' (space), and add 1 to the index of the word in the map for each one. But since we marked word.toLowerCase(), JUMPED and jumped will be treated the same.

Afterwards, we write our output to another file, which after the code is ran will look like this:
    2 the

```
2 quick

2 brown

1 fox

2 jumped

1 lazy

2 dog
```

Comment: I tried to implement this code to see if it would work, and i've been playing around with it quite a bit, but still cant get it to even compile. The two lines that are giving me trouble are as follows:                                                                      "for (String str : word)" ---> will not compile "can only iterate over an array or an instanceof java.lang.iterable"                                                     "   BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputfile.getAbsoluteFile()));" --> won't compile because "outputfile cannot be resolved"

Comment: @MaxBolin ... Fixed the words part, changed it into the keyset. You're suppose to put the outputfile.